# What does "to rumble one's assurances" mean?

Tags: word-meaning

For instance, in

> He rumbled his assurances to the contrary.

Answer (score 2):

There's no set phrase "to rumble one's assurances" in English. The author is using "rumbled" figuratively to mean that the speaker's voice is very deep, so that it sounds almost like a low rumbling sound rather than actual speech. What the sentence really means is

> He assured [the other person], in a deep rumbling voice, that [whatever they were afraid of] wasn't the case.